# Cannot crop UIImage with respect to Y axis

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage, crop

I am cropping an UIImage using the following code:

```
UIImage *image=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10,10,700, 700);

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
CGImageRelease(imageRef);
```

I am able to crop with a height, but if I increased my Y axis it is not getting cropped.

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10,50,700, 700);
```

Any solutions ?

Comment: What's the size of the original image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this github library which do what you want [imageCroppedToRect](https://github.com/soffes/sstoolkit/blob/master/SSToolkit/UIImage+SSToolkitAdditions.h#L46)

```
- (UIImage *)imageCroppedToRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // CGImageCreateWithImageInRect's `rect` parameter is in pixels of the image's coordinates system. Convert from points.
    CGFloat scale = self.scale;
    rect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * scale, rect.origin.y * scale, rect.size.width * scale, rect.size.height * scale);

    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(self.CGImage, rect);
    UIImage *cropped = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    return cropped;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Logically, for the cropping of the image only the size is relevant. So you have to adjust your `width` and `height` accordingly. The `x` and `y` coordinates of your frame will only change the position, not the size.